# Database access in middleware Laravel 6

Tags: laravel

I would like to retrieve data from the database inside the middleware because I need to verify the token of which domain that can access to my system

[you can see i have a file called VerifyCsrfToken.php that extend from Middleware so I want to get all domain that we have an inside table named domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXf07.png)

Answer (score 1):

Simply user DB to make commands.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use DB;
use Closure;

class CheckAccessToken
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = DB::table('users')->first();
        dd($user);

    }
}
```

Or you can also use the model to access the DB

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use App\User;

class CheckAccessToken
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = User::first();
        dd($user);

}
```

Comment: you can see in my image https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXf07.png I have a file called VerifyCsrfToken.php that this file extends from middleware after get data I would like pass to protected $except = [];